# I'm starting a carpet repair business and my name is Chris. Is Chris's Carpet Repair correct?

Tags: possessives

Is Chris's Carpet Repair correct or should it be Chris' Carpet Repair?

Comment: The apostophe after a final letter s is a bit old fashioned. Just use Chris's ...

Comment: A pretty good rule of thumb that few argue with is _If you want to pronounce this (here Chris's) as two (etc) syllables, use 's_.

Comment: If you want to avoid the "s" and "c" together and the apostrophe issue, you can always call it _Carpet Repair by Chris_.